# Spivak Chapter 3 Question 3.

Tags: functions, polynomials

Working through Chapter 3 of Spivak's Calculus.

The question is:

If $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ are distinct numbers, find a polynomial function $f_i$ of degree $n-1$ which is 1 at $x,$ and 0 at $x_j$ for $j \ne i$. Hint: the product of all $(x - x_i)$ for $j\ne i$, is 0 at $x_j$ if $j \ne i$. ( This product is usually denoted by

$\prod_{j=1,j\ne1}^n (x - x_j)$

I stared at this for awhile and it never made sense. So I went to the answer key so I could work backwards to understand the problem.

The answer is

$f_i(x) = \frac{\prod_{j=1}^n (x-x_j)}{\prod_{j=1}^n(x_i - x_j)}$

I stared at this too and the problem was just as perplexing as before.

I see that the answer expands to

$f_i(x) = \frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\ldots(x-x_n)}{(x_i-x_1)(x_i-x_2)\ldots(x_i-x_n)}$

but so what? How is this a solution to the problem?

Assuming $n = 2$, we would have

$f_i(x) = \frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)}{(x_i-x_1)(x_i-x_2)} = \frac{x^2 - x_1 x - x_2 x + x_1 x_2}{x_i^2 - x_1 x_i - x_2 x_i + x_1 x_2}$

This is some arbitrary rational function. To me, it doesn't feel like an answer.

Here are some specifics I don't understand.

1) I see that we have a sequence of numbers. The index of the sequence is j. What is i supposed to be? Sure $j \ne i$, but how is that different from saying that $j \ne blah$

2) The question says "a polynomial of $f_i$ of degree $n - 1$, which is 1 at $x_i$". Does that mean $f_i(x_i) = 1$ or $n - 1 = 1$ when $x=x_i$?

3) Similarly, what is meant by it equals "0 at $x_j$" ?

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a simple specific example first.  Say we are interested in the points $x_1=1$, $x_2=2$, $x_3=4$.  Then
$$f_1(x)=\frac{(x-2)(x-4)}{(1-2)(1-4)}$$
has the properties $f_1(1)=1$, $f_1(2)=0$, $f_1(4)=0$.  The functions
$$f_2(x)=\frac{(x-1)(x-4)}{(2-1)(2-4)}\quad\hbox{and}\quad
  f_3(x)=\frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{(4-1)(4-2)}$$
have similar properties - check it out.

Saying a function $f$ "is $0$ at $x_j$" is just another way of saying $f(x_j)=0$.

Comment: OK. I see. $i$ is non-iterating index into the sequence. What's also important here is the constraint $i \ne j$ which prevents 0 in the denominator. The fraction allows for $f_i(x_i)$ be the same in the numerator and denominator to be the same (thus = 1) while $f_i(x_j)$ where $j$ is any number in the sequence except $i$ will be 0 because one of the terms in the numerator will be 0.

Comment: All sounds good.  Suggestion: any time you have something like this which is too complicated to understand at first sight, try looking at a specific example - or more than one if necessary.